# PHP: pre-processing jpg image in php to get common Image input 4D-tensor

Tags: php, tensorflow

I have a complex feeder of images, created some months ago, written in PHP.
I wuould like to use the images for classification or others machine learning tasks.
I'm using a pre-trained model with tensorflow docker machine and I send curl requests from my feeder to the model to have the prediction of the class of the image.
I need to transform the images from jpg url to standard image input, to create my curl request, according to this:

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_signatures/images#input

Please, could you suggest how to pre-processing the images?
Thank you.

Update:
I'm using tensorflow serving in the docker image.
I have successfull sent a curl request from a http/apache server to docker open port. The docker image loaded is in this example (half plus two):
https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker
The curl request sent a POST with data '{"instances": [1.0, 2.0, 5.0]}' and returns data: { "predictions": [2.5, 3.0, 4.5] } as in the example.
Now I want do the same loading a pre-trained model in tensorflow/serving and I need to send the list of RGB values in floating point ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.
dtype is:
float32
The shape is:
[batch_size, height, width, 3]
I would like to pre-processing in PHP, if possible.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: This is a pretty open ended question - can you share more about what you've tried and where you have gotten stuck? Code examples showing your work so far might be useful. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some additional guidance.

Comment: I updates to add some clues. Thanks

Comment: That helps. Can you also share the model that you're hoping to use? That would help us understand the format that the model is expecting the inputs to have.